# Set an alarm for tomorrow

Tags: alarm, nexus-5

On my Nexus 5 I want to set an alarm for tomorrow but for the life of me I can't figure out how to do this with the build in Clock application.

I'm sure it's me because I'm sure this couldn't be an oversight by the developers?

Answer (score 6):

Stock clock app doesn't have date reference like today or tomorrow. You can however set alarm for the particular day like Sunday or Monday by clicking the particular days.

[image]

Comment: While there's no Date specifically in the Clock app, if you set an alarm without repeat, it will automatically set it as a one-time alarm. So if it's after 7am today, and I set an alarm for 7am, it will happen tomorrow and not repeat.

Comment: So, setting an alarm on Monday for the coming Friday means I need to set a repeat for Friday and once the alarm has triggered (on Friday) I need to delete it. Clumsy but could work..

Comment: @Luke, or you could set a reminder in Google Calendar - but that's definitely not a very intuitive solution. If you use Google Now and say/type "Set an alarm for 5:00am on Friday", it will automatically create a Calendar reminder. Still, it would be nice to have it all contained in the Clock app.

Answer (score 0):

Use voice and say 'Wake me at 7am' and it should set a one time no repeat alarm for the next instance of 7am.